# Alternative to Compiz-Annotate for Kubuntu

Tags: kubuntu

I'm looking for a way to freehand draw on my desktop so I can take screenshots like the one used in [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/138032/172224). I have the screenshot tool already setup I just need the Annotate functionality without installing Compiz.

I'd like to avoid the overhead of a standalone application like Shutter or Inkscape - unless there's a very streamlined workflow for quickly:

1. Annotating the screen (could be across 1 or more running applications)
2. Take a screenshot of the area
3. Upload the image to public hosting (imgur)

Speed is very important - I don't want to wait for a program like Shutter to launch, edit, draw, upload, close. I'd rather just draw, select the area and have the url copied to my clipboard automatically.

Answer (score 0):

**Kaption ?**

http://kde-apps.org/content/show.php/?content=139302

> Description: A KDE utility similar to Jing or Skitch not yet as
>   powerful as them ;)  Nice, but what is it?   It's an app that sit in
>   the systray, left clicking the icon you can capture a screen region to
>   draw arrows, boxes and text  on it, than you can save the result (the
>   screenshots shown here are made with this app).
>
> This program has the following features:  * Screen capture  * Ability
>   to draw arrows, boxes, ellipses and text on the captured region  *
>   Ability to choose color, size and font of your drawings  * FTP/SFTP
>   Upload with clipboard support for custom code. Custom code? It can be
>   a web site pointing to the ftp directory where the image has been
>   uploaded. When the upload finish Kaption will copy the code into the
>   clipboard so you can share the screenshot quickly with anybody

[image]

**PPA Search:**

https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+ppas?name_filter=kaption